# Does Android support 3 or more levels of nested fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm having many crashing issues when programmatically adding 3 levels of nested fragments.
Currently, I have an Activity which loads Fragment A through its fragmentManager, which then loads Fragment B through A's childFragmentManager, which then loads Fragment C from B's childFragmentManager.

The fragments initially load up fine. But the problem is when the fragments are destroyed and then re-created. You'd think that when Fragment B gets destroyed, so will Fragment C. But it seems like Fragment C is left dangling.

As it is now, Fragment B gets loaded through a ViewPager in Fragment A. As I swipe from page to page, I occasionally get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragement no longer exists for key android:target_state: index 1
```

If I remove fragment C from the equation, the error goes away.
It also doesn't crash if I load all fragments in their parent's fragmentManager (instead of childFragmentManager)

Comment: Can you show some of your code? Because I think the index should be 0 not 1 according to your description.

Comment: I have a similar issue, entered as bug here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=54520

Answer (score 2):

The answer is absolutely **yes**. You can have 3 levels. using it successfully in my App.

Comment: @MortezaRastgoo There's no hard limit. Your only limit will be the "StackOverflow" exception you might get if you inflate too many fragments and views among them. Each fragments add a significant amount of views to the Android's view hierarchy.